# Python TypeError on calculator that I'm creating

Tags: python, typeerror

As part of my 'teach yourself python', I am currently creating a GUI calculator. So far I have the interface up and running. And one operation is functional, however, when I reuse the calculator (without restarting the app) I get a "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable", which suggests I haven't nailed the code. Could someone offer some helpful pointers please? Much appreciated.

```
def create_widgets(self):
    """Create buttons, text and entry widgets"""
    # Create a text widget
    self.txt = Text(self, width = 40, height = 1, wrap = NONE, pady = 10)
    self.txt.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 4)

    # Create number 1
    self.btn1 = Button(self, text = "1", command = lambda: self.insert_number(1), width = 10, pady = 10)
    self.btn1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 1, sticky = W)

    # Create number 2
    self.btn2 = Button(self, text = "2", command = lambda: self.insert_number(2), width = 10, pady = 10)
    self.btn2.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 1, sticky = W)

    # Create minus button
    self.btn_minus = Button(self, text = "-", command = lambda: self.operator("-"), width = 10, pady = 10)
    self.btn_minus.grid(row = 1, column = 3, columnspan = 1, sticky = W)

    # Create clear button
    self.btn_clear = Button(self, text = "C", command = self.clear, width = 10, pady = 10)
    self.btn_clear.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 1, sticky = W)

    # Create equals
    self.btn_equals = Button(self, text = "=", command = self.equals, width = 10, pady = 10)
    self.btn_equals.grid(row = 4, column = 2, columnspan = 1, sticky = W)

def insert_number(self, number):
    """insert number to the calculator"""
    self.txt.insert(END, number)

def operator(self, action):
    """Make an addition, subtraction, division or multiplication"""
    self.first_number = self.txt.get(0.0, END)
    self.txt.delete(0.0, END)
    self.operator = action

def equals(self):
    self.second_number = self.txt.get(0.0, END)
    self.txt.delete(0.0, END)
    if self.operator == "-": # If operator is minus
        self.answer = int(self.first_number) - int(self.second_number)
        self.txt.insert(0.0, self.answer)

def clear(self):
    self.txt.delete(0.0, END)
```

Error message when I press the 'minus' button a second time:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Coding\Python Projects\Book\calculator.py", line 33, in <lambda>
self.btn_minus = Button(self, text = "-", command = lambda: self.operator("-"), width = 10, pady = 10)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Include full error in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I have now uploaded the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here: `self.operator = action`

Basically, you set the change the value of self.operator from a method to a string, so when you call `self.operator('-')` you are trying to execute '-', and getting TypeError. I would suggest changing `self.operator = action` to

```
global operator
operator = action
```

and replace `if self.operator == "-":` with `if operator == "-":`

Comment: Thanks, that has worked a treat (I haven't covered global variables yet). From my book, I have learnt to prefix class attributes with "self.", if you wouldn't mind, could you give me a brief understanding of why this is? It isn't explained that well in the book.

Comment: It was the fact that you called a variable with the name of a method, turning the method into the string action. You can simply rename it to something like self.operation, just as long as it isn't the name of a method.